# Django : URL optional paramerter redirection

Tags: python, django

I have a query regarding usage of optional paramaters in Django.

Here is my sample code.

```
url(r'^(?P<type>str)/(?P<term>2006)/$', 'myapp.views.index'),


def index(request, type, term, id = None):
    ..... { some code }
```

So , what i am aiming at is , when i access the url , http://x.x.x.x/myapp/str/2006/ it should display a form with number of ID as a select box. When i select a particular ID and click show, it will show the detailed result on that page itself.

with this current setup, what happens is, when i click the "show button" the form displays the details , but the URL is still http://x.x.x.x/myapp/str/2006/ and not http://x.x.x.x/myapp/str/2006/{{id}}.

This is because i am doing everything in the same view function.

```
def index(request, type, term, id = None):
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'btn' in request.POST:
                .... show details
        else:
                ..... SHow the original form
```

How to achieve this http://x.x.x.x/myapp/str/2006/{{id}} when posting from the same function view.

THanks.

Comment: I'm confused. The url is the same all the time (even if you show details)? or URL can be different, but the view function is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another url regex with the id to your urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<type>str)/(?P<term>2006)/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'myapp.views.index'),
url(r'^(?P<type>str)/(?P<term>2006)/$', 'myapp.views.index'),
```

Comment: Thats not working. i tried that. Hmm. May be i will alter the order in which its parsing. Let me check and confirm.